# Migrating from SQL API to Fusion Tables v1

Tags: javascript, jquery, oauth-2.0, google-fusion-tables

After SQL API was deprecated searching solution to migrate from SQL API
`https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=` to `https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=` like [here](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/migration_guide)

I got:

```
var URLHead = 'https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql='
var URLTable = encodeURI('SELECT id,COUNT() FROM TABLE_ID')
var URLTail = '&access_token='+ TOKEN +'&jsonCallback=?'
var queryURL = URLHead + URLTable + URLTail
var jqxhr = $.get(queryURL, myFT.TABLE, "jsonp")

this.myFT.TABLE = function (DATA) {
  var counter = parseInt(DATA.table.rows[0].toString().substr(1))
  alert(counter )
}
```

I need:

```
var URLHead = 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql='
var URLTable = encodeURI('SELECT id,COUNT() FROM TABLE_ID')
var URLTail = '&access_token='+ TOKEN +'&jsonCallback=?'
var queryURL = URLHead + URLTable + URLTail
var jqxhr = $.get(queryURL, myFT.TABLE, "jsonp")

this.myFT.TABLE = function (DATA) {
  var counter = parseInt(DATA.table.rows[0].toString().substr(1))
  alert(counter )
}
```

Looks like it's not so easy to migrate from `SQL API` to `/fusiontables/v1/` for me.

**EDIT:**
1. Try to change the `jsonCallback` to `callback` - not helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finaly!** Found pure and simple solution by replacing jQuery examp. with [google-api-javascript-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/GettingStarted)

Don't forget to add into head tag
`<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=load"></script>`

```
myTable1 = new FT('table1_id')
myTable1.run('SELECT * FROM ', myTable1, ' ORDER BY id ASC ')

function FT(table_id)
{
  this.counter = 0
  this.table = table_id
  //
  gapi.client.setApiKey('Api_Key')
  //
  this.run = function (q, cls, order)
  {
    gapi.client.load('fusiontables', 'v1', function(){
      var request = gapi.client.fusiontables.query.sqlGet({'sql': q + cls.table + order});
      request.execute(function(DATA){cls.exec(DATA)});
    });
  }
  //
  this.exec = function (DATA)
  { 
    alert(DATA.result.rows.length)
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Or simply just like in first example above change this
`var URLTable = encodeURI('SELECT id,COUNT() FROM TABLE_ID')`
to this
`var URLTable = encodeURI('SELECT COUNT() FROM TABLE_ID')`