# Google fusion table - handling "group by" and "count(col_name)" functions in fusion table

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

Thank you all for your answers:
@ODI - My ultimate requirment is I want to fire the above query and first find related countries and color it and then (not imp now) is to display this count on map.
I am trying the suggestion you mentioned.

@user1224571  - Thank you.

@Eric - Actually the query you posted didnt work. Please find below working code. If you add group by clause it wont work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Fusion Tables Layer Example: Basic Fusion Tables Layer</title>

<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/fusiontables/docs/samples/style/default.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
  function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.0718, -2.768555),
      zoom: 2,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      query: {
          select: 'masterNarrative, (count())',
          from: '1EsjL3dUyez6R8bXlJVtrL8Zq3esRsaoxcamKoVM',
          where : "masterNarrative IN ('Pharaoh','Badr')"},
      styles: [{
          polygonOptions: {
            fillColor: '#00FF00',
            fillOpacity: 0.5
          }
        }]
        //map: map
    });
    layer.setMap(map);
  }


  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess you want to display the result of the query as text and not on a map, right? If so, you should not use the FusionTablesLayer, but instead take a look at the [SQL Reference](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference) and maybe use the [gapi-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/) instead. See [this answer for an example usage of the client](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11747872/549755).

Comment: please find my reply above as main question. I couldnt post my own reply for some stackoverflow restriction

Comment: If you want to use FusionTablesLayer to display data on the map, you must add the location column in the select part (see [the FusionTablesLayer docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTablesConstructor) about that). In your case this is probably the "geometry" column.

Comment: Hi Odi, I changed the query which adds location col but its not displaying count on the map. Below is my new query <br>. How to put this count information on the map? Also this group by clause is not working.<br>           query: {
           select: 'geometry, masterNarrative, (count())',
           from: '1EsjL3dUyez6R8bXlJVtrL8Zq3esRsaoxcamKoVM',
           where : "masterNarrative IN ('Pharaoh','Badr') GROUP BY masterNarrative"},

Comment: You need to add custom data to the [InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows). It's not possible to just add columns to the `select` clause to appear in the InfoWindow. So a combination of the gapi-client and FusionTables will do the trick ;).

Comment: btw: I don't think you can use "GROUP BY" with FusionTablesLayer

Comment: Thank you so much Odi. You have gave me very useful info.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [SQL reference](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference#Select) the count syntax is just count(), not count(column_name).

Comment: please find my reply above as main question. I couldnt post my own reply for some stackoverflow restriction

Answer (score 0):

user1224571 is correct.

Try:

```
query: {
  select: 'master_narrative_name, (count())',
  from: '1hFPiPmQilakQ4zESVCJqq9ENmeo5e_EJXy_Usy8',
  where : "master_narrative_name IN ('Pharaoh','Badr')"  GROUP BY master_narrative_name},
```

Comment: please find my reply above as main question. I couldnt post my own reply for some stackoverflow restriction

Comment: There is a fairly obvious syntax error in my example. The double quote should be at the end of the line.  My experience is that the GROUP BY is required in order to get the count.

Comment: Thanks Eric for your reply but this thing is not working. I have modified the where clause as below, but it's not working.          where : "masterNarrative IN ('Pharaoh','Badr') GROUP BY masterNarrative"